# How to run unit with circle ci in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, circleci

I am having trouble with integrating unit test for my nodejs project. Everything works fine with local when I open one terminal npm start and another terminal run command npm run test. But when deploying it to circle ci I am stuck with the command line start node server. The test statement was not executed. Can someone point me in the wrong direction. Thanks !

This is my config.yml

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  run_tests:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:12
    steps:
    - checkout
    - run:
        name: Install npm dependencies
        command: |
          npm install --save
    - run:
        name: Start node server
        command: |
          npm start
    - run:
        name: Run Unit Tests
        command: |
          npm run test
workflows:
  build_test:
    jobs:
      - run_tests
```

[image: description]

And my repository: https://github.com/ThanhDeveloper/MernStackApp

Answer (score 1):

Try using background option when you start your node app

```
background: true
```

This might change your code to

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  run_tests:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:12
    steps:
    - checkout
    - run:
        name: Install npm dependencies
        command: |
          npm install --save
    - run:
        name: Start node server
        command: |
          npm start
        background: true
    - run:
        name: Run Unit Tests
        command: |
          sleep 1m
          npm run test
    
workflows:
  build_test:
    jobs:
      - run_tests
```

Have added a sleep command for 1m (which is a bit hacky) , you can extend some logic to check if your app is up or not , once it is up then we can run the tests

Reference : https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#run

Comment: Tks for your solution. I will try it later

Comment: @ThanhNguyen if the solution work , please confirm and vote up the answer so that it is helpful for other with similar question

Comment: @ThanhNguyen Did the above solution worked for you ?

Comment: it work for me. Tks for your help @ prudviraj

Comment: @ThanhNguyen can you accept the answer and vote it , so that others can find the solution when they had similar issue